# Pulling data in R into separate data frames, merging and want to make code more condensed

Tags: r, merge, tidyverse, coding-style, subset

I'm trying to pull 2 data frames from a larger data set based off of multiple conditions, group it by a variable, and then merge the subsetted data together.

In this example, I'm pulling from a dataset with individual voters in Florida, including information on whether they voted in 2018 and voted in 2020. I'm trying to look at the % of people who voted in 2018 not 2020, and the people who voted in 2018 and 2020 and compare it side by side.

My question- do I have to create 2 data frames and then merge them to do this? Or is there a shorter/cleaner way than the code I have now?

This is the code I've been using.

```
d <- FL %>% 
 filter(voted_2018 == 1, voted_2020 == 0) %>%  
  group_by(county) %>%  
 count () %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 mutate(prop = n/ sum (n)*100) 


e <- FL %>% 
 filter(voted_2018 == 1, voted_2020 == 1) %>%  
  group_by(county) %>%  
 count () %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 mutate(prop = n/ sum (n)*100) 

f <- merge(d, e, by = "county")
```

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example for testing. Try `FL %>% group_by(county) %>% summarise(n_voted_2018 = sum(voted_2018 == 1 & voted_2020 == 0), n_voted_all = sum(voted_2018==1 & voted_2020 == 1)) %>% ungroup %>% mutate(across(starts_with('n_voted'), ~ .x/sum(.x) *100, .names = "prop_{.col}"))`

Comment: @akrun thank you so much!! the columns with counts look right, but the proportions are off considerably...

Comment: As a note - your code posted above will give percentages of each voting pattern who live in each county. i.e. "what percentage of people who voted in both elections lived in County A?" The percentages in d and e will always add up to 100%.